# tensorflow In python 3.x - You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder' with dtype float

Tags: python-3.6, placeholder

I'm working with tensorflow code in python 3.6. When I try this, an exception occurs:

> InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder' with dtype float
>            [[Node: Placeholder = Placeholderdtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]]

```
import tensorflow as tf

x_data = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
y_data = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]

W = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([1]), name='weight')
b = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([1]), name='bias')

X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)

hypothesis = W * X + b
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(hypothesis - Y))

a = tf.Variable(0.1)

optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(a)
train = optimizer.minimize(cost)

init = tf.initialize_all_variables()

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)

for index in range(2001):
    sess.run(train, feed_dict={X: x_data, Y: y_data})
    if index % 20 == 0:
         print(index, sess.run(cost), sess.run(W), sess.run(b))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is in the last line where you are running the session for cost. 
Try to replace the last line with

```
print(index, sess.run(cost, feed_dict={X: x_data, Y: y_data}), sess.run(W), sess.run(b))
```

This is due to the reason that the **cost** needs to get X and Y data in order to find hypothesis, as you have specified in the code, **which can be given using** **feed_dict** . I have pasted the lines where you are evaluating the cost.

```
hypothesis = W * X + b 
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(hypothesis - Y))
```